# PHP use regex to convert uppercase file extention to lowercase

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to achieve the following conversion:

IM22_htp.JPG -> IM22_htp.jpg

So far I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$string = "IM22_htp.JPG";
$pattern = '/(.+) \.(\w+)/i';
$replacement = '${1}\. strtolower($3)';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: What happens when you run this?  What's the output you see?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be easier if you use [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to extract only the extension, lowercase it and then concatenate it back with the filename.

Answer (score 10):

Using regex:

```
$string = "IM22_htp.JPG";
$new_string = preg_replace_callback('/\.\w+$/', function($m){
   return strtolower($m[0]);
}, $string);
echo $new_string;
```

Using [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$string = "IM22_htp.JPG";
$new_string = pathinfo($string, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '.' . strtolower(pathinfo($string, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
echo $new_string;
```

Comment: For the record, these techniques will reduce the casing of the rightmost substring only.  Effectively converting `TEST.INC.PHP` into `TEST.INC.php`.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/\.(\w+)/',
         create_function('$x','return strtolower($x[0]);'),
         $string);
```

Comment: For the record this will `strtolower()` all occurrences of dot followed by word characters. `TEST.INC.PHP` becomes `TEST.inc.php`  Also the capture group is pointless in this implementation. P.s. please always explain your answers.