# Changing case with regex

Tags: php, regex

I was looking for this for a while, but was not able to find any answer. I need to change a string to lowercase in PHP.
Off course, this can be done by using `strtolower()`, but I was wondering if its possible to do it via `preg_replace()`.
I noticed that in vim one can use `\L` or `\U` modifiers in the back references to change the case to lower or upper.

Is something like that possible to do in PHP, i.e. in the second argument in `preg_replace()`? The reason why I wanna change the case via `preg_replace()` is that I heard that it might work better for `UTF8` strings (not sure if its true).

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [my earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15349032/). You can do it with the `e` modifier, but that's bad. I suggest to do it `with preg_replace_callback()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should actually just use

```
 mb_strtolower($str, 'UTF-8')
```

That way you specify utf-8 is the encoding, and all should work well.

Edit: sorry had strtoupper, changed to lower.  Also, you can leave off utf-8 and it *should* automatically detect the encoding and use the right one.

Comment: +1. Just remember that this extension is not enabled by default. See http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php for how to enable it.

Comment: Yes, but mb_strtolower() might not be available as mbstring is a non-default extension.

Answer (score 0):

Doing with preg_replace is **practically impossible**.

This is because you need to pass the `strtolower()` / `strtoupper()` as a parameter to `preg_replace` function. Since `preg_replace` cannot act on their own.

Go with the function what **Dave** suggested.